# Echo MySQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please tell me why this isn't working. When I run the query in PHPMYADMIN it reports the correct value.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT('id') AS RowCount FROM 'needs' WHERE ('status'=100)");


echo $result;
```

Comment: stop using mysql it is deprecated, use PDO or mysqli! read documentation!

Answer (score 1):

You're combining mysqli and mysql_ functions. Either use mysqli, or use mysql_. But note, mysql_ functions are deprecated for security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Hi You need this code.

```
//If the query returns more 1 row you must use this.
...
$query = "USE database_name; SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS RowCount FROM `needs` WHERE (`status`=100);"

$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {  
     DO{
        echo $row["RowCount "];  
        }WHILE ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }
// now if you query returns only 1 wor use this.

$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rowQry= mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $rowQry["RowCount "];
```

Luky

Comment: Can you please explain how this answers the question?  Without that, this is just code.

Comment: @Luky I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: (¬_¬)" ... Really? Are you missing something in your strange code? Cause I saw what are you missing. Read the error @user2520794.

Comment: If you're going to rewrite the code to use only one mysql api, **don't use the obsolete one**. Use mysqli.

Comment: @user2520794 The parse error is NOT coming from `$result...` but elsewhere. This answer is wrong and for a lot of reasons.

Comment: there was a missing semi-colon at the end of the $query line. No errors now, now the result just shows up blank with no value.